# Help with a "tougher tuesday" crossword puzzle on "animal opposites"

Tags: crossword-clues

I assume this must be some obscure word play that I can't figure out. The overall clue of this NYT style crossword puzzle is "Animal Opposites".

The three clues relevant to this overarching clue and their answers are:

1. A bird of prey without a mate? --> Lonesome Hawk
2. Where you might buy an albino beast of burden? --> White Donkey Sale
3. What a photographer of hunter in Alaska might do? --> Shoot the Bear

I got these based on the other letters and so on, but I can't for the life of me figure out how these answers fit into the overall clue. Sure, they're animals, but I don't get the "opposites" part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the author has done is take a phrase involving animals and changed the animal to an opposite one.

So we have:

> [Lonesome Dove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonesome_Dove) : Dove (pacifist) becomes a Hawk (predator). From [Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/doves-and-hawks).
>
> [White Elephant Sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_elephant_sale) : Elephant (Republicans), Donkey (Democrats) [@Deusovi]
>
> [Shoot the Bull](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+the+bull) : Bulls and Bears from the Stock Market.

Comment: "Elephant" and "Donkey" are opposites because of US politics -- the elephant is the symbol of the Republicans, and the donkey is the symbol of the Democrats. (These are the two major opposing US political parties.)

Comment: Ah, so tricky. I was focusing my "opposite-finding" efforts on the adjectives...